# Iterate over a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to iterate over a list in pandas to fill the other column

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([{'A': [5, 6, 7], 'B': ""},
               {'A': [3, 4, 7], 'B': ""},
               {'A': [3, 0, 4], 'B': ""}])
```

I tried:

```
def fill_row(df):

    for elmts in range(len(df["A"])):
        if elmts == 4:
            df["B"] == 4
        else:
            df["B"] == 0

    return df

df["B"] = df["A"].apply(fill_row)
```

My output:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Good output:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([{'A': [5, 6, 7], 'B': 0},
               {'A': [3, 4, 7], 'B': 4},
               {'A': [3, 4, 4], 'B': 4}])
```

Comment: `df["B"] = df["A"].apply(lambda d: 4 if 4 in d else 0)`?

Comment: @ladybug, can you add the logic of `B` column values? It is not clear why `B` column value is `0` or `4`. Moreover, `A` column last value is also changed in the output. Can you add the logic of the output to the question?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in 1 line:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 4 if 4 in x else 0)
print(df)

           A  B
0  [5, 6, 7]  0
1  [3, 4, 7]  4
2  [3, 0, 4]  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` on pandas 0.25+:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].explode().eq(4).any(level=0).astype(int) * 4
```

Or just a simple list comprehension:

```
df['B'] = [4 if 4 in x else 0 for x in df['A']]
```